# amqpstorm connection timed out

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqpstorm

I have rabbit running in a docker container on myserver.com

I tried the example from https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm but i get connection timed out when trying to connect to remote rabbit.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
    packages/amqpstorm/connection.py", line 70, in __init__
self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
packages/amqpstorm/connection.py", line 192, in open
    self._wait_for_connection_state(state=Stateful.OPEN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/amqpstorm/connection.py", 
line 315, in _wait_for_connection_state
raise AMQPConnectionError('Connection timed out')
amqpstorm.exception.AMQPConnectionError: Connection timed out
```

The code i use is this:

```
from amqpstorm import Connection
from amqpstorm.exception import AMQPConnectionError

try:
    with Connection('myserver.com', 'username', 'password') as connection:

        with connection.channel() as channel:

            channel.queue.declare("my_queue")

            properties = {
                'content_type': 'text/plain',
                'headers': {'key': 'value'}
            }

            channel.basic.publish(body="Hello World",
                              routing_key="my_queue",
                              properties=properties)
except AMQPConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
```

This works if i setup rabbit locally and connect with 127.0.0.1.
Rabbit on the remote machine is up and running and i can access from myserver.com:55672.

I have also tried setting the port as argument with no effect.

Comment: This would indicate some sort of issue connecting to the RabbitMQ server. Are you sure the port ```55672``` is the actual amqp port? You can view the listening ports if you go to the web panel, and check under ```Ports and contexts```.